# AJAX - How can I build a notification system, that is constantly getting updated, without slowing down my website too much?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database, performance

I am a beginner to web development, and I am trying to do a notification system with AJAX and jQuery.

In my web application, I have a comment system where you can mention another user. After a comment mentioning a certain user has been written, a new entry on my `notifications` table will be added, containing the comment, the `id` of the user who commented and the `id` of the user(s) who will receive the comment. After the notification is stored in the database, I want the person that was mentioned to receive the notification.

To that effect, I decided to use AJAX. Using the `setTimeout()` method, I am sending an AJAX request to the database every 2 seconds, and with that, I can display the notifications visually to the user that is meant to receive them.

My only concern is that this will slow down the site once I connect it with a server.

So, I was looking for a way that would allow me to implement a notifications system without slowing the site too much, since the one that I am using currently doesn't seem very efficient.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If you are a beginner, then you should probably not try coding this from scratch. Search for a JavaScript notifications framework to get started.

Comment: for the record, I adamantly disagree with @w.PatrickGale ... learn how to do things from scratch, *before* using pre-made solutions.  There's a bigger learning curve, but you'll be a much stronger programmer in the end.

Comment: ...that said, check out "[ask]'.  Your question needs to be more specific, including the section of code you're having trouble with, so the problem can be reproduced ...and so others know that you tried. (Otherwise it can come across as *"show me how to build a notification system"*, even if it's not intended that way.) See also, how to build a "[mcve]"